# Get current image of kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I use `kubectl` or the API to retrieve the current image for containers in a pod or deployment?

For example, in a deployment created with the below configuration, I want to retrieve the value `eu.gcr.io/test0/brain:latest`.

```
apiVersion: v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: flags
   spec:
     replicas: 6
     template:
       metadata:
      labels:
        app: flags
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: flags
           image: eu.gcr.io/test0/brain:latest
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

From `kubectl` 1.6 the `-o wide` option does this, so

```
kubectl get deployments -o wide
```

will show the current image in the output.

Comment: For all namespaces, add `-A`.

Answer (score 59):

You can use kubectl's [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) output option to achieve this:

```
kubectl get deployment flags -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'
```

Comment: You'll need single or double quotes surrounding the JSONpath filter if you're using the zsh shell. It's a good practice to always use them.

Comment: This is actually the only expression that worked for me to find out the image used in a multicontainer pod. This command shows only the image of the first container in contrast to all containers when you use "{..image}". 
And in my case I needed exactly this behavour!

Answer (score 21):

to get just the image uri for all pods (in all namespaces, for example):

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}"`

(see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/ for more detail)

Comment: work for me.
For a single image:
kubectl get deploy/deployment-name -o jsonpath="{..image}"

Comment: That shows you the images on the currently running pods. If your deployment has failed, for example if you have a crash in your app code that prevents the pod from starting, you may have a different image in the deployment than you have on the pods that are still running.

Answer (score 14):

For a single deployment use this:

```
kubectl get deploy/deployment-name -o jsonpath="{..image}"
```

It can work for pod too

```
kubectl get pod/pod-name -o jsonpath="{..image}"
```

Comment: Here's the [Kubernetes reference for JSONPath-support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

Answer (score 13):

You can list all deployments' image tag in a list:

```
kubectl get deployment -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{':\t'}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.image}{', '}{end}{end}"
```

Sample output:

```
deployment-a:   docker-registry.com/group/image-a:v1,
deployment-b:   docker-registry.com/group/image-b:v2,
deployment-c:   docker-registry.com/group/image-c:v3,
deployment-d:   docker-registry.com/group/image-d:v4,
```

Comment: command without line breakes `kubectl get deployment -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'\n'}{.metadata.name}{':\t'}{range .spec.template.spec.containers[*]}{.image}{', '}{end}{end}"`

Answer (score 7):

the following worked for me:

```
kubectl get deployment -o=jsonpath='{$.items[:1].spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'
```

..my deployment config was clearly different (with 'items' element at the start) for some reason.

UPDATE:
The 'items' element (which is just a list of deployment elements) will appear if just doing:

```
kubectl get deployment -o=json
```

whereas if I specify the deployment name, there'll be no items element in the returned json, e.g.:

```
kubectl get deployment [deploymentName] -o=json
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use,

`kubectl  get pod <pod_name>  -o yaml| grep image:`

And from deployment,

`kubectl  get deploy <deployment_name>  -o yaml| grep image:`

Answer (score 4):

Approaches mentioned in other answers like

```
kubectl get deployment deploymentname -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'
```

return image even if current rollout is unsuccessful. Use this approach if you want to get image from successful/running pod

```
kubectl get po -l app=deploymentname --field-selector status.phase=Running  -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}'
```

Answer (score 3):

To get all the images being used by the deployments, you can use below command.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' |\ sort
```

Answer (score 2):

I often use this for gaining better image insight into a pod:

```
kubectl get   --output json pods \
  | jq '.items[] .status.containerStatuses[] | { "name": .name, "image": .image, "imageID": .imageID }'
```

Ouputs:

```
{
  "name": "app-admin",
  "image": "***docker_app-admin:v1",
  "imageID": "***docker_app-admin@sha256:2ce3208649e72faaf1fe8be59649de01b36f656866498b46790adaf154eefc6b"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom column to get the image name

```
kubectl get deploy -o custom-columns=DEPLOYMENT-NAME:.metadata.name,IMAGE-NAME:.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get deployments.apps -n admin2406 -o=custom-columns=DEPLOYMENT:.metadata.name,CONTAINER_IMAGE:.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image,READY_REPLICAS:.status.readyReplicas,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Arora, please add a comment to explain your answer, Thanks!

Comment: This command utilize custom-columns option where we can specifically list columns from the json structure of the service description. In my version CONTAINER_IMAGE:.containers[*].image worked. To get correct path of your version use get pods with -output json option to see location of image node in json.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for deployment, it would be deployment specific, but if one wants to search images in all objects like: deployment, statefulset, demaonset, jobs etc, the following simple command would do the trick:

```
kubectl get all -n <namespace> -o jsonpath={..image}} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question has already been answered, I wanted to provide an example using Go templating:

```sh
kubectl get deployment $GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME \
--namespace=$GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE \
--output=go-template \
--template='{{range .spec.template.spec.containers}}{{.image}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'

#=>

us.gcr.io/. . ./. . .:xxxxxxx
```

**Note**: if your `deployment` contains more than one container, this command will list **all** Docker Images; since `containers` is either a JSON array or YAML sequence, there is no guaranteed order.  I.e. selecting by element index isn't guaranteed to return the intended Docker Image Repo. and Tag.

**Note**: if you are using this command in order to determine what `git` `commit` is currently deployed, through Docker Tags or Docker Labels, you will need to introduce string manipulation.

You may want to `label` your `deployment` *instead*:

```sh
kubectl label \
--overwrite=true \
deployment $GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME \
commit=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) \
--namespace=$GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE \
--record=true

#=>

deployment.apps/$GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME labeled
```

and access this `label`, regardless of multiple Docker Images and **without** string manipulation, using:

```sh
kubectl get deployment $GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME \
--namespace=$GKE_DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE \
--output=go-template \
--template='{{index .metadata.labels "commit"}}{{"\n"}}'

#=>

xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer give hint but if someone is looking for working example as asked in question

```
kubectl -n dev get sts  -l 'app in (app1,app2)' -o wide --no-headers | awk '{print $5}'
```